# Drop down menu pushes content downwards

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

A top dropdown menu next to the logo pushes the main webpage downwards when clicked. How is it possible to just overlay the content instead? Thanks in advance.

Comment: post some css, what positioon are u setting to the menu ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make your dropdown `position: absolute`. Then it won't take up any layout space.

Comment: Thanks guys tried absolute but needs to be centred. Now have this css but the dropdown won't drop down now (have updated webpage): <div class="main" style="position:relative; margin:auto; padding:0; z-index:800;">

Comment: Your jsfiddle still pushes the content down. What do you mean by centered? Do you want the dropdown to be in the middle of the page?

Comment: check this, http://jsfiddle.net/pMD5D/2/ u need to set absolute to your main menu

Comment: Problem is that it needs to be centred relative to the body but the main issue is it either pushes down or in safari it does not show at all. Ta

Answer (score 1):

You need to make it `position:absolute`, like skyuzo says.

Then you need to manually position it where it needs to be.  Get the position of the element you want to dropdown from (use `offsetLeft`, and `offsetTop`), then set the top and left style properties of your dropdown.

Use a JS toolkit to make life easier :)

Absolute positioning takes the element out of the layout, but that means you can't rely on the element being positioned where it normally is.